# Изменение объема swap'а в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, swap

При запуске утилиты `free` в Ubuntu 16.04 показывается информация об использовании оперативной памяти, а также swap. Насколько я понимаю, swap'а выделяется столько же, сколько предустановленно оперативной памяти. Есть ли способы увеличения swap'а? Или же такая необходимость отсутствует по причине самостоятельного увеличения swap'а при недостатке свободного места?

Comment: *Насколько я понимаю, swap'а выделяется столько же, сколько предустановленно оперативной памяти.* - нет, отдельный дистрибутив может такое делать, но выводить это за правило я бы не стал. *Есть ли способы увеличения swap'а?* - да, сгенерировать файлов и/или разделов на диске под это дело и подключить через swapon (/etc/fstab для перманентного эффекта). *Или же такая необходимость отсутствует по причине самостоятельного увеличения swap'а при недостатке свободного места?* - боюсь, такой штуки не существует, по крайней мере по умолчанию.